# How to run Node.js files in eclipse?

Tags: javascript, eclipse, node.js

I successfully installed the plugin for **node.js** on **eclipse Kepler**, but when I write JavaScript code in a node project and then run it, it looks like nothing happens. I have also downloaded node.js of the [nodejs.org](http://nodejs.org) website, and I have been able to run files that I have created in notepad and then ran on the command prompt fine. Now I want to run everything in an editor and because I have used eclipse before I thought I would use it again. I wish I could be more descriptive but thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can directly press `ctrl+F11` shortcut or you can run from toolbar and see results in cosole. You can also browse to the path from your browser to see things printed to browser.

PS - `Also select Window -> Open Perspective -> Node`